# How to get an update on CollectionViewSource.View.Count in UWP

Tags: uwp, collectionviewsource

I am retrieving the `FileInformation.DisplayName` property of circa 5k files in a folder using `FileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedFilesVector()` to display them in a GridView in UWP via a `CollectionViewSource`. While the display works, I fail to obtain the proper count of the items that have been retrieved.
I am aware that I can do this by awaiting `GetFilesAsync` and count but this kills the speed purpose of using  the virtualized vector, and hence I would like to avoid it.

Here is the XAML

```
    xmlns:ba="using:Windows.Storage.BulkAccess"


    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Margin="16">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <AppBarButton Icon="Folder" Click="AppBarButton_Click" LabelPosition="Collapsed"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh" Click="RefreshAppBarButton_Click" LabelPosition="Collapsed"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="infoTextBlock" FontWeight="Medium"/>
    </StackPanel>


    <GridView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind FileCollectionViewSource.View, Mode=OneWay}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="ba:FileInformation">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DisplayName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind

```
    private StorageFolder _folder;
    public CollectionViewSource FileCollectionViewSource { get; set; } = new CollectionViewSource();

    private async void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var folderPicker = new FolderPicker
        {
            SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary,
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
        };

        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        _folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (_folder != null)
        {
            GetFileVectors();
        }
        else
        {
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Pick folder";
        }
    }

    private void GetFileVectors()
    {
        var queryOptions = new QueryOptions
        {
            FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep,
            IndexerOption = IndexerOption.UseIndexerWhenAvailable
        };

        var fileQuery = _folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

        var fileInformationFactory = new FileInformationFactory(fileQuery, ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, Constants.Thumbnail_Size,
            ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale, false);
        var filesVector = fileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedFilesVector();

        FileCollectionViewSource.Source = filesVector;

        var count = FileCollectionViewSource.View.Count;
        infoTextBlock.Text = $"View count {count}";//Returns 0
    }

    private void RefreshAppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        infoTextBlock.Text = $"View count {FileCollectionViewSource.View.Count}";//returns the correct count
    }
```

Results:
When I choose a folder, the method GetFileVectors() is invoked, it performs the bulk search and sets `FileCollectionViewSource.Source = filesVector;`, and `FileCollectionViewSource.View` is `OneWay` bound to the `GridView`. However, `FileCollectionViewSource.View.Count` returns 0 at this stage.
If now I click on the refresh button `RefreshAppBarButton_Click` then the exact count is returned.

I can imagine that `FileCollectionViewSource.View` needs some time to settle, and indeed setting an `await Task.Delay(1000)` before printing out `FileCollectionViewSource.View.Count` works, but I am looking at a way to update the `TextBlock` when `FileCollectionViewSource.View` is done.

Is there a way to do that automatically by some event or other?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to listen `FileCollectionViewSource.View.VectorChanged` event? if the count changed, it will invoke `VectorChanged method.

Comment: Yes I tried this and it worked, but I found it an overkill as this event is fired as we scroll the gridview, so I had to put a check as shown in the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following  Nico Zhu - MSFT, fire an event after the source has been set`FileCollectionViewSource.View.VectorChanged += View_VectorChanged;`

then

```
  private void View_VectorChanged(IObservableVector<object> sender, IVectorChangedEventArgs @event)
    {
        if (@event.CollectionChange == CollectionChange.Reset)
        {
            infoTextBlock.Text = $"{FileCollectionViewSource.View.Count} ";//returns the correct count
        }
    }
```